# Are @PathVariable or @RequestBody needed in external function signature?

Tags: java, rest, jpa, request, annotations

I have one question about convention. Everything works ok (thanks god), but I am not sure, if annotations (@PathVariable and @RequestBody) are needed in my AttributeService class method signature:

```
@Autowired
private AttributeRepository attributeRepository;

public Attribute create(@RequestBody Attribute attribute) {
    return attributeRepository.save(attribute);
}
```

It will probably work with, or without them, but do they have any purpose outside my @RestController controller?
Controller method looks like this (here I need these annotations of course):

```
@PostMapping(consumes = "application/json")
public Attribute create(
        @RequestBody Attribute attribute
) {
    return attributeService.create(attribute);
}
```

I mean, it makes me confused if I browse my service class and I see yellow annotations, and I am mistaken that I am in Controller class :)

Another question, is it okay if they have the same name "create"? Name of controller's method does not actually matter, because it is called automatically, but I am asking about convention. I find it easy to make them with same name, so I know quickly match that create() from controller is calling create() in service (if I have many methods like this).

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no sense in using `@RequestBody` in methods of your `AttributeService`. No framework will ever process this annotation.

In my opinion, read for `GET`, create for `POST`, update for `PUT` and delete for `DELETE` are good method names for HTTP methods, respectively. As you stated, any name will work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these annotations are needed to provide automatic deserialization of the text in the response body or path variable to the corresponding Java object in the Controller.  In your service class you work with the Java object, so these annotations are redundant here.

As for the naming convention, it's up to you and your peers :)